# Valgrind - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value, fscanf

Tags: c, valgrind

I was testing my program in valgrind an i've recived this error message:

```
==12097== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12097== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12097== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12097== Command: ./a.out
==12097== 
==12097== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12097==    at 0x4C34CF9: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12097==    by 0x10945F: read_dict_word (main.c:146)
==12097==    by 0x10952D: load_dict (main.c:155)
==12097==    by 0x109D29: main (main.c:297)
==12097==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12097==    at 0x1093A8: read_dict_word (main.c:142)
==12097== 
==12097== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12097==    at 0x4C34D08: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12097==    by 0x10945F: read_dict_word (main.c:146)
==12097==    by 0x10952D: load_dict (main.c:155)
==12097==    by 0x109D29: main (main.c:297)
==12097==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12097==    at 0x1093A8: read_dict_word (main.c:142)
==12097== 
==12097== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12097==    at 0x4C34DEC: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12097==    by 0x1094D2: read_dict_word (main.c:147)
==12097==    by 0x10952D: load_dict (main.c:155)
==12097==    by 0x109D29: main (main.c:297)
==12097==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12097==    at 0x1093A8: read_dict_word (main.c:142)
==12097== 
==12097== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12097==    at 0x4C34E08: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12097==    by 0x1094D2: read_dict_word (main.c:147)
==12097==    by 0x10952D: load_dict (main.c:155)
==12097==    by 0x109D29: main (main.c:297)
==12097==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12097==    at 0x1093A8: read_dict_word (main.c:142)
==12097== 
==12097== 
==12097== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12097==     in use at exit: 500 bytes in 35 blocks
==12097==   total heap usage: 110 allocs, 75 frees, 18,844 bytes allocated
==12097== 
==12097== 500 (272 direct, 228 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==12097==    at 0x4C33D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12097==    by 0x109442: read_dict_word (main.c:145)
==12097==    by 0x10952D: load_dict (main.c:155)
==12097==    by 0x109D29: main (main.c:297)
==12097== 
==12097== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12097==    definitely lost: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==12097==    indirectly lost: 228 bytes in 34 blocks
==12097==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12097==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12097==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12097== 
==12097== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12097== ERROR SUMMARY: 13 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here's the code of mentioned section:

```
int read_dict_word(passwords_dict_holder* holder, FILE* file)
{
    char buffer[WORD_SIZE];
    int result = fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);
    holder->dictionary = (char**)realloc(holder->dictionary, ++holder->dict_size * sizeof(char*));
    holder->dictionary[holder->dict_size-1] = (char*)malloc((strlen(buffer)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(holder->dictionary[holder->dict_size-1], buffer);
    return result;
}
```

I guess valgrind doesn't like the fact, that I'm using locally created variable in strlen(), but how do i avoid that when I need to set it based on string read from file?

Comment: 1) Never user `"%s"`,  Use a width like `"%99s"` when `WORD_SIZE = 100`. 2)  Code needs to check `result` _before_ `strlen(buffer)`.

Comment: I think valgrind found a memory leak. perhaps you are allocating space for your dictionary and forgetting to free it somewhere? Do you free it at the end of your code? Do you free it before reallocating it to increase it in size?

Comment: @JacobGlik doesn't realloc free previously taken memory automatically?

Comment: @Grzegorz Smolak you are right! looks like I've got to catch up on c allocation functions

Comment: To add to @chux comment, better use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`. Also check `file` is not `NULL` if not done by the caller.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 1)hmm... i guess the name of this constant is irrevelant, should have been BUFFER_SIZE instead. Words i pass to the buffer have not constant length, does it mean i still should use "%99s"?
2)I'm not sure what do you mean by that, I would appreciate if you explained it further

Also I'm sorry if I speak total nonsense, but im fairly new to programming

Comment: For 2 - if `fscanf` fails then `buffer` will be uninitialised. That's probably exactly what is happening. And that's why you must check the return value of all functions. For 1 - nothing to do with the name. More that you need to ensure a width is used like `%99s` to ensure it doesn't overflow the buffer.

Comment: @GrzegorzSmolak In your code `scanf` will return 1 if it succeeds. It will return 0 or EOF if it fails. If the `scanf` fails, it will not write anything to the buffer, so the buffer remains uninitialized. So the code should check that `result == 1` before doing anything with the contents of the buffer.

Comment: @kaylum oh yeah, that makes sense and it's probably the reason, thanks a lot!
1) thats actually smart, havent thought about it, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @user3386109 looks like you are right, thanks!